# Unit Testing with Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I'm using PHP with Laravel 5.5 framework.
I recently started writing unitTests for my code and I got a few questions:

1. What is the best way to interact with my database? 
   Should I use InMemoryDB like SQLite or Mock everything with Mockery.
2. If I have an interaction with DB than that is still unitTesting or Integration Testing?

Thank you for the answers in advence

Comment: Database testing is not unit testing. This is quite a [broad topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing) you asked here. Since you asked such question, meaning you don't know much about testing, there's quite a big possibility your code is written in a manner it's not possible to unit test.

Comment: I just started diving into unitTesting, so that is true that my code may not testable...anyway, thank you for the clarification

Comment: Read the [Laravel Docs on testing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/testing), it explains the differnce between unit testing and feature testing.

Answer (score 0):

I work in a company where we strive for 80% code coverage, in general we test mostly End-2-End, with database and mocking external calls, we use SQLite so our testsuite can run quickly in a local environment. When the case make sense, we unit tests it, as an example an Tax service i did for different countries i unit tested, because it was very input output based.

Why we prefer End-2-End:

- It's quicker if you don't have to make unit, integration and end to end testing
- You test the endpoint will actually will be used
- I prefer to run with a real database if you are running with Continous Integration

There is drawbacks with SQLite, mainly it does not work as other RDB where there is a lot of settings and limitations, on top of my head i had problems with foreign key enforcing etc.

So to answer your question:

- It's smart to use SQLite at least locally
- In Unit Testing you are only testing one class and mocking everything else, you are basically testing that the code can execute. Note this is a oversimplified version on a very complex subject.

Comment: side note: I used SQLite at first for testing, however due to differences in database engine this proved to not work long term.

Comment: Martin ever heard about the [Test Pyramid](https://www.google.com/searchq=pyramid+test)? Code coverage should only be measured when doing unit tests and ignored while doing E2E tests.

Comment: Yes, but the way Laravel development goes, this is how people like to do it and the way i like too. From my experiences most company will skim on testing and not test at all. In my department we have been in companies that heavily rely on unit testing and we felt like it sometimes was a bit to much and you where missing the mark, how testing out of the box is structured in Laravel you can do E2E with a test instance of your application. So when i talk E2E i need to specify that i only worked in API development.

Comment: @Thomas my team experienced the same, but we go great lengths to support it for the time we save running test locally and quick tests locally is even something Uncle Bob advertises :)